# How can I use Kotlin Compose to plot a line chart or graph?

Tags: android, kotlin, plot, android-jetpack-compose, linechart

I am learning Kotlin with Compose but have experience in Python. I want to just do a basic line chart plot. Is that possible in Kotlin with Compose?

I do not need anything fancy. If it's ugly, that's fine.

When searching on the internet I only find homemade packages, and non made for compose. Isn't there a standard way of making a simple plot?

Comment: There are [many posts and libraries on making charts](https://jetc.dev/search?q=chart), such as [this library](https://github.com/hi-manshu/Charty), [this library](https://github.com/KoalaPlot/koalaplot-core), [this library](https://github.com/fracassi-marco/JetChart), and [this library](https://github.com/ellsworthrw/DiamondCharts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to charts in compose there is no functions by default for it, so you have two choices:

**1. Create you own chart:**
In jetpack compose there is a composable called [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/overview) which have multiple functions and features to help draw anything you want and you can create a chart with it, **but i wouldn't bother if you need a basic chart(pie, plot...)**.

**2. Use a third party library:**
There are a lot of open source libraries made by wonderful people you can use i would suggest:

[Vico](https://github.com/patrykandpatrick/vico)

[Ycharts](https://github.com/yml-org/YCharts)